# Moodle + nginx = 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, moodle, bitnami

I use nginx+letsencrypt as proxy in docker, that's my nginx.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    container_name: nginx-proxy
image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
restart: always
ports:
  - 80:80
  - 443:443
networks:
  - proxy
volumes:
  - /myfolder/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
  - /myfolder/nginx/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
  - /myfolder/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  - /myfolder/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

nginx-proxy-letsencrypt:
  container_name: nginx-proxy-letsencrypt
  image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
  restart: always
  volumes: 
  - /myfolder/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
  - /myfolder/nginx/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
  - /myfolder/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  - /myfolder/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
environment:
  - NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER=nginx-proxy
networks:
  - proxy

networks:
  proxy:
   external: true
```

It works normally with different programs in other containers when I write in configs of that programs:

```
VIRTUAL_HOST: my.host.com,www.my.host.com
REDIRECT: my.host.com
LETSENCRYPT_HOST: my.host.com
LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: admin@host.com
```

But it doesnt work with moodle (because we have apache builted in moodle), that's my moodle.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:10.2'
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - /myfolder/moodle/db_data:/bitnami/mariadb
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: MyPassword
      MARIADB_USER: admin
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: MyPassword
      MARIADB_DATABASE: moodledb
  networks:
    - moodle

moodle:
  image: bitnami/moodle:3.11.5
  container_name: moodle
  restart: always
  environment:
  - MOODLE_DATABASE_HOST=db
  - MOODLE_DATABASE_NAME=moodledb
  - MOODLE_DATABASE_USER=admin
  - MOODLE_DATABASE_PASSWORD=MyPassword
  - MOODLE_USERNAME=admin
  - MOODLE_PASSWORD=MyPassword
  - MOODLE_EMAIL=admin@host.com
  - MOODLE_SITE_NAME=MyMoodle
  - VIRTUAL_HOST=lms.host.com,www.lms.host.com
  - REDIRECT=lms.host.com
  - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=lms.host.com
  - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=admin@host.com
  - MOODLE_HOST=lms.host.com
  - MOODLE_REVERSEPROXY=true
  - MOODLE_SSLPROXY=true
  volumes:
  - /myfolder/moodle/data:/bitnami/moodle
  - /myfolder/moodle/moodledata:/bitnami/moodledata
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    args:
    - EXTRA_LOCALES=ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8, ua_UA.UTF-8 UTF-8
  depends_on:
    - db
  networks:
    - moodle
    - proxy
  
phpmyadmin:
  image: 'phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin'
  container_name: moodlepma
  restart: always
  environment:
    PMA_HOST: db
    UPLOAD_LIMIT: 1000M
  depends_on:
  - db
  networks:
  - moodle

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
  moodle:
```

Moodle logs:

```
moodle 20:22:03.76 
moodle 20:22:03.76 Welcome to the Bitnami moodle container
moodle 20:22:03.76 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-moodle
moodle 20:22:03.76 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-moodle/issues
moodle 20:22:03.76 
moodle 20:22:03.76 INFO  ==> ** Starting Moodle setup **
realpath: /bitnami/apache/conf: No such file or directory
moodle 20:22:03.80 INFO  ==> Configuring Apache ServerTokens directive
moodle 20:22:03.83 INFO  ==> Configuring PHP options
moodle 20:22:03.84 INFO  ==> Setting PHP expose_php option
moodle 20:22:03.86 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_CLIENT_* env vars
moodle 20:22:03.87 INFO  ==> Validating settings in POSTGRESQL_CLIENT_* env vars
moodle 20:22:03.97 INFO  ==> Restoring persisted Moodle installation
moodle 20:22:04.98 INFO  ==> Trying to connect to the database server
moodle 20:22:05.01 INFO  ==> Running database upgrade
moodle 20:22:05.29 INFO  ==> ** Moodle setup finished! **
moodle 20:22:05.30 INFO  ==> ** Starting cron **
moodle 20:22:05.32 INFO  ==> ** Starting Apache **
[Sat Apr 09 20:22:05.363075 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 1] AH01909: www.example.com:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Apr 09 20:22:05.363392 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 1] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Apr 09 20:22:05.381122 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 1] AH01909: www.example.com:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Apr 09 20:22:05.381382 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 1] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Apr 09 20:22:05.389028 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1d configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 09 20:22:05.389060 2022] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/bitnami/apache/bin/httpd -f /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/httpd.conf -D FOREGROUND'
```

I never used nginx before. Maybe trouble somewhere in apache configs. Can anyone help me with it? :(

Comment: `[Sat Apr 09 20:22:05.381382 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 1] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name`

Do you actually use `www.example.com` as domain name in your server configuration?

Comment: Of course not, but I don't know how to fix it, I tried to add this in yml config: 
      - /myfolder/moodle/conf/lms.conf:/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/lms.conf:ro
with this settings:
    <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName lms.host.com
 ServerAlias www.lms.host.com
 ServerAdmin admin@host.com
 DocumentRoot /bitnami/moodle
    </VirtualHost>
But it doesn't help me... I sure that the trouble somewhere in apache configs, but I don't know where.

Comment: I suppose, you need to tune your apache config directly, at least consider reading or dumping to understand what is under the hood and what is actually parameters your web server runs.